# Python umlaut character issue - mbcs needed , is there a better way for all characters

Tags: python, utf-8, ansi, mbcs

I was having trouble with Python script opening a file which contained an umlaut character. Naturally I thought I could correct this with a unicode  utf8  fix, but not so...

I ended up using the **mbcs**      ( default is  cp1252)

Then I wrote this statement of which I wish to write MUCH cleaner,

```
def len(fname):
i = -1
try:
    with open(fname, encoding='mbcs') as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    try:
        i = -1
        with open(fname, encoding='utf8') as f:
            for i, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        i = -1
        with open(fname) as f:
            for i, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
return i + 2 # 2 because it starts at -1 not 0
```

Comment: What encoding does your file have? Maybe you should simply use that one.

Comment: Seriously, @Hyperboreus is definitely right. Figure out the file's encoding.

Comment: Also this python [unicode page](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) is a great primer in file encoding.

Comment: And btw "mbcs" is not an encoding, but stands for "multi-byte character set". From the docs: "on Windows, Python uses the name “mbcs” to refer to whatever the currently configured encoding is"

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Or, rather, `"mbcs"` is an encoding, but one that's not known until runtime, and is in fact _never_ known by the programmer or the script, only by Windows itself…

Comment: @abarnert The idea that there is wisdom unbeknownst to man, and only known by Windows itself, scares me.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: This is one of those cases where knowledge does not necessarily imply wisdom. :)

Comment: Data is originally in Teradata Warehouse, sent to SQL Server stored in varchar

Comment: @TomStickel And what is the encoding of that varchar column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost certainly going about this all wrong, as explained in the comments… but if you really *do* need to do something like this, here's how to simplify it:

The general solution to avoid repeating yourself is to use a loop. You've got the same code three times, with the only difference being the `encoding`, so loop over three encodings instead. (In your case, the third loop didn't pass an `encoding` at all, so you do have to know the default value of the parameter, but [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) or `help` will tell you that.) The only wrinkle is that you apparently don't want to handle exceptions in the third case; the easiest way to do that is to reraise the last exception if they all fail.

While we're at it: There's no need to "declare" `i` up-front the way you do; the `for` loop is just going to start at 0 and erase whatever you put there. That also means the `+2` at the end is wrong. But there's an easier way to get the length of an iterable in the first place: just feed it into something that consumes generator expressions. A custom `ilen` function written in C would be ideal, but people have tested various different Python implementations, and `sum(1 for _ in iterable)` is almost as fast as the perfect solution, and dead simple, so it's the most common idiom. If this isn't obvious you to, factor it out as a function and call it `lien`, and give it a nice docstring and/or comment. Or just [`pip install more-itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) and then you can just call [`more_itertools.ilen(f)`](http://pythonhosted.org/more-itertools/api.html#more_itertools.ilen).

Anyway, putting it all together:

```
def len(fname):
    for encoding in 'mbcs', 'utf8', None:
        try:
            with open(fname, encoding=encoding) as f:
                return sum(1 for line in f)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            pass
    raise e
```

Comment: I had to make a small modification since the raise fails due to the e variable losing scope.   Thus  def len(fname):
    encoding = ['mbcs', 'utf8', None]
    for enc in encoding:
        try:
            with open(fname, encoding=enc) as f:
                return sum(1 for line in f)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            if enc == encoding[-1]:
                raise e
            else:
                pass

Comment: @TomStickel: If you're going to do it that way, just use `raise` inside the `except`, not `raise e`. It's a bit hard to explain why in a comment, but the short version is: if you can re-raise from an except, you should, especially in Python 3 but even in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not entirely clear to me what you want: if you just want to count the lines, ignore the errors! – This is pretty safe, as practically all encodings use the same ASCII compatible line endings (except UTF-16...).

`open(fname, errors='ignore')`

And you never get an exception. Done.

Comment: I still need it to fail for example if a file does not exist.   Or if someone tries to transmit a binary file.

Comment: @TomStickel: What exactly is a "binary file"? That's not a rhetorical question; your existing code (and my answer) says that anything that isn't valid as a text file in the current Windows MBCS codepage, or UTF-8, or the OEM codepage is binary. That means that, e.g., UTF-16 text files (which are pretty common on Windows) will be treated as binary. On the other hand, if the OEM codepage is one of the extended-Latin ones, almost _nothing_ will be treated as binary.

Comment: @TomStickel: 1) It does fail if the files does not exist, of course! 2) so you want to use 3 character encodings to test if it’s a text-file or not??